# API calls using postman causing issues

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

Can someone please help me fixing the Postman Desktop agent issues.

- When I try to send a request using postman web, where the send button disabled and saying that to install Desktop Agent.
- I have already installed Desktop Agent and it's running. Also, I've changed the postman agent to desktop from the bottom of the postman web(using play button)
- But still i'm unable to make api calls and the send button still disabled and saying to install desktop agent.
- I've even tried multiple times restarting my laptop, uninstall and re-installing postman desktop agent.

**Note** - i'm unable to use cloud agent, as i'm sending https requests to my local node application and it's on organizational asset.